# SQL: How to add an if to a while loop if @@fetch_status = -1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, while-loop

I am refactoring a stored procedure that uses a local cursor to iterate through each records of a table named productagg and perform various operations specific to the record(s) in that table.

This loops executes as long as there is a record in the table, which will return a non -1 status.

I need to add a scenario in which, either inside or outside the loop, I need to perform the same set of operations for when there is no record in the productagg table. In that case, I just want to perform operations for all products.

Here is the basic, current structure of the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE productagg_cursor CURSOR LOCAL
FOR SELECT                      
     [ProductID]
    ,[MaxItems]
    ,[RegionID]                         
    FROM [dbo].[ProductAgg]
    WHERE [ProductAggID] IS NOT NULL;

OPEN productagg_cursor;     

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; -- TURN IT ON

FETCH NEXT  FROM productagg_cursor 
INTO 
        @ProductAggID
,       @MaxItems
,       @RegionID;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1


    In here the operations based on the record that set the cursor id value happen.



    FETCH NEXT FROM productagg_cursor INTO 
            @ProductAggID
    ,       @MaxItems
    ,       @RegionID;

END; -- END WHILE 

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; -- TURN IT OFF

CLOSE productagg_cursor;

DEALLOCATE productagg_cursor;
```

My request is to perform the same operations that are based on a *productaggid*, as if there was no product specified in the productagg table. The operations would be performed for all products and not just from the productagg table.

Will this part be added as an If statement that checks to see if the return from the productagg table is > 0 if it is then it executes everything that includes the cursor and while loop, and if the opposite, it will perform an else? Or is another way that this can be done? Any ideas and examples would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this would be a good time to consider refactoring the cursor out of this and while you are it and a good opportunity to stop using read uncommitted. You really should read more about isolation levels. Using read uncommitted is incredibly bad when you are doing updates. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this, where there is separate code?

```
if @@FETCH_STATUS = -1
begin
   print 'No Rows'
end
else while @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
begin
   print 'Rows'
   -- fetch next
end
```

Or like this, where the same block of code executes regardless?

```
while 1=1
begin
   -- do something whether or not there is data
   if @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 break
   -- fetch next
   if @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 break
end
```